# In client side javascript, how can change my variables based on environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok, so I am using node.js and it is awesome.

I have been working locally until very recently and I am a bit frustrated that I am changing my code each time just to deploy.

Specifically I am using socket io and I need to tell the socket where it lives:

```
var _socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
```

When I have been going locally, this is great, but I need to change this each time I deploy to my test server...this is annoying. In other languages I can do this through a config file.

In node, on the server side, I can set variables based on my environment like so...

```
app.configure('development', function(){
    process.env.PORT = 5000;
});
```

Can I do something similar on the client side?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886773/socket-io-hardcoded-vs-dynamic-connection-url

Comment: You can make a server-side route that serves a client-side JS file with configuration from your environment.

Comment: I think it's worth drawing attention to the fact that it's ideal when prepping builds to create artefacts that can be deployed to any environment - i.e. you shouldn't have to make environment specific builds. See 12factor where it talks about Build-Release-Run. You should be able to combine your environment specific config at release time with a completely environment agnostic build artefact. Any solution to your problem that requires parameterising your build is not a good idea. You should find a way to pass config to the client at runtime (e.g. like Slaks suggests above)

Answer (score 1):

You have to embed this variable to client-side HTML code somehow (i.e. in Jade templates).

If you show your server-side code serving HTML, I might be able to pinpoint where it might be.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do stuff like this:

```
(function(){
var config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8080',
    setEnv: function(env){
        switch (env){
            case 'development':
                this.host = 'devserver';
                this.port = '80';
                break;
            case 'production':
                this.host = 'prodserver';
                this.port = '80';
                break;
        }
    }
};

   console.log(config.host);
   console.log(config.port);
   config.setEnv('production');

   console.log(config.host);
  console.log(config.port);
})();
```

Comment: If you do this, don't you have to remember to change the setEnv before you deploy?

Comment: Yes, however you could use something like jade to set a hidden field value, or even emit the value from Node with jade to a javascript variable or a hidden input.  Then your client-side javascript would read that value and pass it in on page load.  I prefer global namespaced libs that get included in a jade layout file that all pages extend so that I can control it in one place rather than do this on each page.

Answer (score 1):

If you build your application with grunt then use [grunt-variablize](https://github.com/msn0/grunt-variablize). Put your configuration into `resources/config.json`

```
{
  "test": {
    "socketUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
  },
  "prod": {
    "socketUrl": "http://your-production.com:5000"
  }
}
```

configure variablize task:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  /* ... */
  variablize: {
    target: {
      input: "resources/config.json",
      output: "dist/config.js",
      variable: "Config",
      property: grunt.option('profile')
    }
  }
});
```

run `grunt --profile=test` or `grunt --profile=prod` and use it this way:

```
var _socket = io.connect(Config.socketUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends, how you are managing on node side. Like if you have different config file for each env. eg. production.js, development.js etc. Then you can define url in that config or set an env. Set this base url or env. into the server side HTML template and render.
on Client side you can easily read the env. or base url. in my case i had set of url based on environment. I defined the environment in config file and on client side created a config file. So that based on env. config file can set the URL.

```
    angular.module('core').constant('config',{
    'apiUrl' :{
            'beta': 'http://api-beta.xyzdev.com',
            'dev': 'http://api-dev.xyzdev.com',
            'production': 'http://api-prod.xyzdev.com'
        }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

On the client side, this should be enough:

```
var _socket = io.connect();
```

socket.io will detect automatically the host and the port.

**edit**

If the url matches the address and the port, you can also do:

```
var _socket = io.connect(document.location.protocol+'//'+document.location.host);
```

Comment: For some reason if I remove the hardcoded address my server gets cranky...I know this should work, but it doesn't for me. More generally though, I need to do more than just get the socket connection. I just used this as an example.

Comment: How do you include socket.io.js? With an actual copy of the js file or dynamically simply with `/socket.io/socket.io.js` letting node find it for you?

Comment: I have a copy of the actual JS file.

Comment: @David did you try the second option in my answer?